# foreach loop inside html table design in laravel

Tags: laravel, foreach, laravel-5.4

I have an array of data to display using table in html .but  the foreach loop which i m using is not giving the desired format .
Below is the array data

```
$data =  Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 10
            [asset_name] => Mini Paver
            [qty] => 3
            [est_start_date] => 02/05/2017
            [days] => 2
            [comments] => Comment 2
            [bundle_name] => 1XRoller 1XPaver
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 11
            [asset_name] => Roller
            [qty] => 2
            [est_start_date] => 03/07/2018
            [days] => 4
            [comments] => Comment 2
            [bundle_name] => 1XRoller 1XPaver
        )
)
```

my view html code :

```
@foreach($data as $value) 

<table class="" style="width: 100%;border:1px solid #ccc">
<thead>
 <tr>
    <th colspan="4"> <p><?php echo $value['bundle_name'];?> </p></th>
  </tr>
<tr>
    <th style="text-align: center">id</th>
    <th style="width:5%;text-align: center">Asset Category</th>
    <th style="width:5%;text-align: center">Days</th>
    <th style="width:5%;text-align: center">Qty</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>

    <tr>
        <th style="text-align: center"><?php echo $value['id'];?> </th>
        <th style="width:5%;text-align: center"><?php echo $value['asset_name'];?></th>
        <th style="width:5%;text-align: center"><?php echo $value['days'];?></th>
        <th style="width:5%;text-align: center"><?php echo $value['qty'];?></th>
    </tr>
                                 
</tbody>
</table>
@endforeach
```

By using above for each loop i m getting the below html format like `bundle name` is repeating .[image]

But i need the output should be like as below :
[image]

that means i want the bundle name shluld come only one time and the rest of details should display as in rows .
How do i do that ? any suggestions please ?
Thank you .

Comment: your bundle_name will be same for all the items? or will it vary?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try the below code,
I have assumed the below points,
1. Your bundle_name will change(that is you will have various bundle_name). This code will work even if you have single bundle_name.
2. You will sort the result by bundle_name.
3. You need bundle title & table header for each bundle_name(again, this code will work even if you have single bundle_name).
4. bundle_name will never have a value false.

```
@php ($bundle_name = false)
@foreach($data as $value) 
    @if($bundle_name != $value['bundle_name'])
        @if($bundle_name != false)
                </tbody>
            </table>
        @endif
    @php ($bundle_name = $value['bundle_name'])
    <table class="" style="width: 100%;border:1px solid #ccc">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th colspan="4"> <p> {{ $bundle_name }} </p></th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th style="text-align: center">id</th>
                <th style="width:5%;text-align: center">Asset Category</th>
                <th style="width:5%;text-align: center">Days</th>
                <th style="width:5%;text-align: center">Qty</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
    @endif
            <tr>
                <th style="text-align: center">{{ $value['id'] }} </th>
                <th style="width:5%;text-align: center">{{ $value['asset_name'] }}</th>
                <th style="width:5%;text-align: center">{{ $value['days'] }}</th>
                <th style="width:5%;text-align: center">{{ $value['qty'] }}</th>
            </tr>
@endforeach
</tbody>
</table>
```